# How to configure rabbitmq with mongo?

Tags: mongodb, rabbitmq, docker-compose

How to configure rabbitmq with mongo?

how to configure rabbitmq image (https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/) for save messages in mongo and not in files.

It is possible?

Comment: Are you asking how to write "consumed" messages to mongo, or how to store persistent messages to mongo?

Comment: We have a problem in the company I work, when the rabbit image is removed from the docker container we lost all the messages. And I havent found a solution for this problem yet

Comment: Well sure, that's how docker containers work - once stopped, they return to "image state", unless you commit... And just a small correction: you can't really "remove image from docker container", you can stop the container which is actually a running instance of an image :) What you could do is write a small consumer that would consume all the messages from every exchange and log the to mongo...

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible?

no.

RabbitMQ does not provide a way to change it's internal storage